# Unknown pseudo-op: `.pushsection'. AS version 2.29.1

Tags: gcc, assembly, cygwin, gnu-assembler

Cygwin x86. GCC version 7.3.0. Assembler version 2.29.1. 
I am trying to build Seabios (CSM16.bin). But i have error:

```
stacks.s: Assembler messages:
stacks.s:139: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.pushsection'
```

As version is not very old. But why assembler dosn't understand opcode?
Sorry for my english...

Gcc -v:

```
Используются внутренние спецификации.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Целевая архитектура: i686-pc-cygwin
Параметры конфигурации: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.i686/src/gcc-7.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.i686/src/gcc-7.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Модель многопоточности: posix
gcc версия 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any hidden control characters in the file?  Or maybe bad line-endings?  `.pushsection` is a valid GAS directive.

Comment: I don't know. Version is not old. In linux all builded successfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/PushSection.html) `.pushsection` is one of the ELF section stack manipulation directives. The cygwin target is not ELF, it's COFF/PE. As such that directive is not available (even though it would make sense).

Comment: silent pain (((

Comment: @ldrt Try passing options to the assembler such that an ELF object is generated.  GNU as should be able to do so, even on COFF targets and GNU ld should be able to work with ELF objects, even on COFF targets.  Since seabios does not run on Windows, this should work.